# C# Timer doesn’t work when it’s called for more than an hour

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

When I call this function, TimeElapsed is written correctly, but the timer itself doesn’t work. For example if I call it every minute, it works, but if it is called once at 2 hours, that doesn’t work.

```
public static void StartTimer(Quiz quiz)
    {
 
        Console.WriteLine("Time from TimerClass: "+StudyDay.GetNearestLesson());
        if (StudyDay.GetNearestLesson().TotalMilliseconds <= 0)
        {
            quiz.BotWorks = false;
        }
      
        var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = StudyDay.GetNearestLesson().TotalMilliseconds;
        aTimer.AutoReset = false;
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((object obj, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)=>quiz.Show(quiz));
        aTimer.Start();
    }
```

GetNearestLesson return time correct, it returns double.
quiz.Show calls StartTimer function in its end.

Comment: Nothing is retaining your timer -- it will get garbage collected at some point. Make sure you store it in a field somewhere.

Comment: Why is your `aTimer` locally declared inside `StartTimer` method?

Comment: Could you please suggest some solution? In case that this function is called Cyclically(every time `quiz.Show` ends. @canton7 Thanks

Comment: I said "*Make sure you store it in a field somewhere*". That also lets you cancel a running timer, if necessary

Comment: From the code you've given we cannot tell what the value of `StudyDay.GetNearestLesson().TotalMilliseconds` actually is. It could simply be that it's not the value you expect it to be. We need the full code with sample data to really determine what's going on. We need a [mcve].