# Task.Delay() doesn't work with big TimeSpan (an hour), but works with smaller (10 minutes)

Tags: c#, async-await, task

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using Telegram.Bot;

namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public class TimerClass
    {
        public  static async Task StartTimer(Quiz quiz)
        {
            while (StudyDay.GetNearestLesson().TotalMilliseconds > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Time from TimerClass: " +
                    StudyDay.GetNearestLesson().TotalMilliseconds);
                await Task.Delay(StudyDay.GetNearestLesson());
                quiz.Show(quiz);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("END");
        }
    }
}
```

`StudyDay.GetNearestLesson().TotalMilliseconds` gives a correct result.
If time is a minute or 10 minutes, my program works, but if it's an hour, my programs doesn't work. May the reason be that my Mac goes into sleep mode, while this app is running? Please show me how to change my program^-^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Timer doesn’t work when it’s called for more than an hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72123962/c-sharp-timer-doesn-t-work-when-it-s-called-for-more-than-an-hour)

Comment: I what context is this code used? Is this a website, a console application, WPF, what is it?

Comment: "my programs doesn't work" - Exactly *how* does it not work? If your computer is sleeping it will obviously not run your program. So a good start might be to ensure it does not go to sleep mode, and if that turns out to be the problem, try to solve *that* problem.

Comment: I don't think that [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72123962/c-sharp-timer-doesn-t-work-when-it-s-called-for-more-than-an-hour) is relevant. A `System.Threading.Timer` can get garbage collected if it's not stored somewhere, but a `Task` created by an asynchronous method is not garbage collected before its completion, even if it's not stored anywhere.

Comment: You operating system may offer features to wake up at a certain time.

Comment: Did you try `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(StudyDay.GetNearestLesson()))` ?